# ASP.NET ListBox DataBind Previous Selected Values

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listbox

The Standard ASP.NET `ListBox'`s got a `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` used for data binding, what I am looking for is like a `DataSelectedField` property.

E.g. I've got a database that contains previously selected values that I just want to re-bind to the `ListBox`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Just to give everyone more of a clue what I am looking for, look at the following code:

I've got a listbox:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lbxStuff" SelectionMode="Multiple">
</asp:ListBox>
```

Setting its values:

```
public static List<Triplet> GetDummyData()
{
    return new List<Triplet>
    {
        new Triplet("A", 1, true),
        new Triplet("B", 2, false),
        new Triplet("C", 3, true)
    };
}

protected void BindList()
{
    List<Triplet> items = GetDummyData();
    foreach (Triplet item in items)
    {
        lbxStuff.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.First.ToString(), item.Second.ToString())
        {
            Selected = (bool)item.Third
        });
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindList();
    }
}
```

But it feels overkill to have to do it like this, there must surely be a better/faster more standard way of achieving this? Like via an `ObjectDataSource`? Else I must add my own `DataSelectedField` property via `WebControlAdapter`? (again overkill)

Comment: If you have them in your database already, what is the problem with binding them to the listbox?

Comment: Well, editing them again, e.g. ListBox contains A,B,C only B is selected, sooo when editing I want to re-bind, showing B is selected and allow the user to make other new selections.

I know how to do this programatically, I just want to know what the best way is to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, ViewState could be used I think, you could keep the selected row's id in ViewState and after binding you could set the selected row of the listbox with that value.

Comment: Just to give you a real world scenario: An administrator selects roles for an user from a ListBox of roles.

Comment: This just feels like something thats standard, obvious and general , that it feels weird that their wont be a standard implementation.

Comment: Yes, it looks obvious and I can't see any performance loss or anything negative for an ordinary data binding.Elders might finde a way, try to keep your question active by editing with new things you do, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think something along these lines should do the trick:

```
public static List<Triplet> GetDummyData()
{
    return new List<Triplet>
    {
        new Triplet("A", 1, false),
        new Triplet("B", 2, true),
        new Triplet("C", 3, false)
    };
}

protected void BindList()
{
    var dummyData = GetDummyData();

    var selected = (from item in dummyData
                   where item.Third = true
                   select item).First();

    lbxStuff.DataSource = dummyData;
    lbxStuff.DataTextField = "First";
    lbxStuff.DataValueField = "Second";
    lbxStuff.DataBind();

    if (selected != null) lbxStuff.SelectedValue = selected.Second
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindList();
    }
}
```

Comment: mmmm, the idea is to "bind" the third value seen in the Triplet, thats the value that indicates its selected, like seen in the example snippet, you're actually throwing it away completely

Comment: My apologies for misreading your post.  I have altered my answer to include a rough stab at a LINQ query that should allow you to tell the ListBox which ListItem to select based on what's returned from the DB.